# draggingEntered: called but performDragOperation: not on IKImageBrowserView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, ikimagebrowserview

I'am using the IKImageBrowserView with setting a drop deleagte

```
[self.imageBrowserView setDraggingDestinationDelegate:self];
```

No matter what i return in draggingEntered: the performDragOperation: gets never called

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    // GETS CALLED 
    return NSDragOperationEvery;
}

- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    // NOT CALLED
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    // NOT CALLED
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `draggingUpdated:` must be implemented.